# Localized Xpages application multiplying properties files

Tags: xpages, domino-designer-eclipse

Yet another weird story from Domino Designer 9.0.1:

The application in question is set to support German and English; German is set to be both the source and the default langauge.

Over the course of the past few weeks we observed that there are some CustomControls and Xpages whose properties files are multiplying; within something like 12 hours we often see hundreds of multiplied files (currently we have 120 multiplications; earlier this week we had a case with > 1000 multiplied propertiey files!) In package explorer they turn up like this:

[image]

As you can see there is something like a docUnid added to the property's file name. Apart from a different time stamp they all are identical internally. In same cases both language versions are multiplied, in this particular case here only the German (= source) version shows that phenomenon.

Another strange fact: this particular custom control hasn't changed for quite a while, and it only contains a single  control with a static text attribute, alongside a

Anyone having an idea what could be causing this, and what possible solutions I could try?

Tech facts and some more observations:
Domino Designer 9.0.1 FP6, ExtLib 17; we are working in a team where each one of us is coding in their own local replica, then replicating into the "hub" replica. I can't prove it but I assume that there is a connection between one of us replicating updates and the creation of new prüperty duplicates

**EDIT:** some more observations: I think I was able to pin it down to the replication between two specific machines; I just ran a sequence of 5 or 6 manually driven replications between both instances, every time *without* making any changes to the design code on either side. nevertheless every replication reported exactly 1 update and 1 addition, and each time a new property file was added.

So meanwhile I deleted the custom control in question and rebuilt it from scratch under a slightly different name (just to be on the safe side). For now it seems that the application is "behaving" now but I'm sort of sure that this will return sooner or later.

Comment: Have you tried exporting this as DXL and seeing how has edited them last or matching the time with when someone is replicating ?
Perhaps they are replica conflicts when you work on a local copy and that one updates the properties and someone else also got updates to them.

Comment: no , I haven't exported this as DXL yet. If I do, what would you remmend I should be looking for within the DXL code? Meaqnwhile I ran a few more tests, see the EDIT part above

Comment: Date time stamps and authors.
I would also try to delete the local replicas on there machines and recreate them.

Comment: the latter is what I'm doing each morning... I'll have a look at author and time stamps as soon as this re-occurs. Thanks. - just out of curiosity: have you ever encountered somiething like that yourself? Cause I haven't, but this is the first time we are working on an XSP project as a team

Comment: I think replication of design elements does not create conflicts nor copies shown in your screenshot. IMO the problem is in source control configuration by some of your developers. Replication probably creates conflicting file on filesystem that is replicated back to hub replica.

Answer (score 0):

Speak after me: source control and replication do not match.

More details:
The property files get stored as attachments in a design note. That's usually the note with the form. Unless you switch on multi lingual, then each property gets its own note. When different people work on the database these note elements get recreated on build getting the next UNID kind of.

So the right flow for what you try to do: pick your best version of the nsf. Nuke the other replicas. Bind it to version control. Let your peer developer create an nsf from that repository. Sync of design shall only happen via that repository.

While your on it: add Bavarian as language, so your Munich customers can use the app too

Comment: I can confirm that this phenomenon occurred on our database when source control isn't used, and I'm the only developer. The design is not in a template database, or you could say that the design database is also the test database. Not the best situation, I know... Usually, I remove all properties files that have a UNID in their name. It hasn't happened for quite a while now.

Comment: Switch to source control. Don't replicate

Comment: I will, some day. I disabled source control a few days ago, it proved to be a disaster for the classpath file: source directory and jar-file disappeared too often. See one of my other questions.

Comment: I know you strongly recommended going source control just the other day. I have to admit we didn't obey you, for some good reasons. So source control at least in this case can't have anything to do with our problem. Then emotion line is that this is coming solely from standard replication. If, however, replication and standard XSP localisation don't match then I wonder what will happen to all those customers that are running replicating Domino servers -  should we start checking for multiplying property files?

Comment: That only happens when multiple people touch different replicas with designer

Comment: oops, tablet typo; just in case, someone was wondering: "Then emotion line..." was supposed to be "The bottom line...". - Apart from that I strongly hope you're right; in our case it also happened without anyone making any design changes on any side. Although I have to admit, that both replicas were *open* in deisgner while I forced replication... I'l keep an eye or two on it. And: many thanks for sharing your knowledge...